# Huge memory usage when running huggingface transformers run_language_modeling.py with GPT2

Tags: machine-learning, torch, huggingface-transformers

I tried to test [`run_language_modeling.py`](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/examples/language-modeling/run_language_modeling.py) with a small test file and it run out of memory after using more than 32 GB of RAM. Why does it need so much RAM or what am I doing wrong?

Command line:

```
python run_language_modeling.py --output_dir foo --model_type gpt2 --model_name_or_path gpt2 --do_train --train_data_file test.txt --no_cuda --eval_data_file test.txt
```

Testfile size: 29600 bytes, 546 lines.

With the original OpenAI implementation I have no problem to run the training script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their new [run_clm.py](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/examples/pytorch/language-modeling/run_clm.py) script does not have the problem and the old script seems now to be unsupported anyway.